# Normal distribution for a given range of numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, range

My question is about estimating a normal distribution for a row of points of an interval that are extracted from the data, just knowing the maximum (`xmax = 200`) and minimum (`xmin = 100`), to distribute them randomly by an average and an associated standard deviation that we will estimate.

Is there a method in Matlab, or the literature to do it, such that when you draw the associated law, we must not exceed the `xmin` and `xmax` values?

I used this trick:

```
x = xmin + rand (1, n) * (xmax-xmin);
```

but I do not know how to extract the parameters of the normal distribution (the mean, the standard deviation).

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to generate data:

```
pd = makedist('Normal','mu',0.7777777,'sigma',0.3333333);
t = truncate(pd,0,1);

r = random(t,100000,1);
histogram(r,100)
```

*Based on example code from the [MATLAB `truncate` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.truncate.html).*

If you're wanting to fit a model to some data to extract parameter estimates (using the above data as example):

```
x_min = 0;
x_max = 1;

heaviside_l = @(x) 1.0*(x>=0); %define double Heaviside function, because in Matlab 2017 Heaviside returns sym instead of double
heaviside_r = @(x) 1.0*(x<=0); %Heaviside function, which equals zero on the right

normcdf_lr = @(mu, sigma) (normcdf(x_max, mu, sigma) - normcdf(x_min, mu, sigma));
norm_trunc = @(x, mu, sigma) normpdf(x , mu, sigma)./normcdf_lr(mu, sigma) .* heaviside_l(x - x_min) .* heaviside_r(x - x_max);

[phat, phat_ci]  = mle(r , 'pdf', norm_trunc,'start', [mean(r), std(r)])
```

*Using code from [Fitting a truncated normal (Gaussian) distribution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64040-fitting-a-truncated-normal-gaussian-distribution).*

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to use `randn` for a normal distribution - `rand` will draw from a uniform distribution.

Calling `randn(1,n)` will return *n* normally distributed samples from the standard distribution with mean of zero and a variance (standard deviation squared) of one. To change the mean of this distribution to an arbitrary `x` and the standard deviation to `y`, simply do `x + y*randn(1,n)`.

If you expect the mean to be, say, 150 and the standard deviation to be 25, you would accomplish this as follows:

```
>> stddev = 25;
>> xmin = 100;
>> xmax = 200;
>> xmean = 150;
>> n = 10000;
>> out = xmin + ( (xmean-xmin) + stddev * randn(1,n) );
```

And you can verify that `mean(out)` and `std(out)` are approximately 150 and 25, respectively. **However** - for a large *n* and a sufficiently large `stddev`, you are pretty much guaranteed to get some samples less than `xmin` and some greater than `xmax`. You can set these back to your limits in just a couple lines:

```
>> out( out<xmin ) = xmin;
>> out( out>xmax ) = xmax;
```

or just remove those entries entirely (so the length of `out` will be less than `n`):

```
>> out( out<xmin | out>xmax ) = [];
```